# How to keep development links pointing to localhost while in development in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm not sure of a good title for this question but I'm wondering why, in development (running `gatsby develop`), all my relative links are directed to my production URL. I am using Gatsby Link and relative URLs for all of these links, too.

For example, in development, let's say I'm linking to my about page `<Link to={'/about'}>About</Link>`, I expect the link to go to `localhost:8000/about` but it goes to `https://myproductionsite.com/about`

I assume this has something to do with my `gatsby-config` file:

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
        title: "My site name",
        description: "...something about providing services",
        author: "Me",
        siteUrl: "https://myproductionsite.com",
        ...
```

I think things were working fine before adding `siteUrl` which I use for SEO purposes, so I don't want to get rid of it, but I can't remember at what point I noticed this happening. I'm way too far down the road to start digging through commits.

I'm wondering if there's an obvious fix to this.

I tried setting up `env` vars in `.env.production` and `.env.development` and using a switch statement in my Gatsby config to dynamic select the value of `siteUrl` but that didn't seem to work or have any effect.

For example:

```
// .env.development
SITE_URL=localhost:8000
```

The expected behavior, when clicking on links while in development, is to default to `localhost:8000` as the root domain, and convert to the production root when the site is live.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? Thx.

Comment: How are you using `<Link>` component? By default, it points to `localhost` in both cases when working in local environment

Comment: The standard way. A `<Link>` tag with a closing tag and a `to` attribute with a relative path, type string. I show an example in my question.

Comment: Imported from Gatsby?

Comment: Yes, like this in my components `import { Link } from "gatsby"`